# How to upload same file in different folder?

Tags: yii2

I have this following controller, I want to upload same file and save in different folder, but my second `saveAs()` didn't work.

```
$model->profil_picture_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'profil_picture_file');
$model->profil_picture_file->saveAs('path to first folder'); //it works image saved
$model->profil_picture_file->saveAs('path to second folder'); //doesn't work not saved
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong? and why it error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @MarkHall no error, image just not saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
$model->profil_picture_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'profil_picture_file');
$model->profil_picture_file->saveAs('path to first folder', false); //set deleteTempFile  param to false
$model->profil_picture_file->saveAs('path to second folder'); //it will work now and delete temp file
```

`saveAs()` accept 2 params - `file` and `deleteTempFile`

Docs: [Yii2 UploadedFile::saveAs()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#saveAs()-detail)

Answer (score -2):

because file `saveAs` use `move_uploaded_file` which move file, so the second `saveAs` doesn't work because file already moved. So, use `copy('path to first folder', 'path to second folder')`